# How do I disable the Home encryption offered during install?

Tags: filesystem, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption)

During install I ticked the box to enable encryption for my Home directory. I'm concerned that it is effecting performance and I'd like to disable this option.

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://askubuntu.com/q/4950