# How to get rid of home data encryption?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the Home encryption offered during install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9922/how-do-i-disable-the-home-encryption-offered-during-install)

I have installed Ubuntu as a virtual machine on my Windows machine. During installation I selected to use home directory data encryption. Now I have a problem that I am running out of disk space on my virtual machine. *Disk Usage Analyzer* tool shows that *.ecryptfs* folder occupies the same amount of disk space as my home directory. What do I have to do to get rid of this directory and would it be safe?

Comment: .ecryptfs is using the same amount of space as your home folder because it is your (actual) home folder. The data is not duplicated. ~/.ecryptfs contains the encrypted files, and ubuntu mounts it over your ~ and decrypts the files on the fly.