# How do I DISABLE home directory encryption during Ubuntu 12.04 installation?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, encryption, home-directory

When attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a CD, there is an option displayed for "Encrypt my home folder".  The option is checked (enabled) by default, but it is grayed out, so it is impossible to uncheck it.

I do NOT want my home folder encrypted.  How do I disable this option *before installation*?

Please note that this is NOT the same as asking how to revert home folder encryption *after* installation.  The following post explains how to do that:
[How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption)

A related post (9922) seems to have been trying to ask exactly the question that I am asking, but was *erroneously* marked as a duplicate of 4950.  Hence, the link to 9922 now *erroneously* forwards to article 4950:
[How do I disable the Home encryption offered during install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9922/how-do-i-disable-the-home-encryption-offered-during-install?lq=1)

EDIT: I am using the 64bit Desktop image ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Which iso did you download?

Comment: The 64bit Desktop image ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this as well, specifically *after* a prior install where I had chosen for an encrypted home directory.

Deleting all existing volumes and partitions on the disk through a separate tool seemed to fix the problem, and now the options are all selectable again.