# Can you unencrypt / remove encryption from a user home folder?

Tags: encryption, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption)

During installation I have chosen to encrypt my user's home folder.

Can I un-encrypt it? How would I do that? I just want it to be "normal" again.

Comment: I should ask: why would you want to do this? Encrypted or unencrypted, it makes no difference to operations except your stuff isn't plastered across the Internet because some hacker found it.

Comment: @David Its messing up some services I need to run after login, I am sure its the encryption on the home folder since same version in a vbox without encryption where I do my tests on runs perfect. I can try to fix the service scripts with delays or simply remove something I do not need on this machine.

Comment: I thought that might be it. The reason for the problems is that the encrypted home is actually only mounted (or decrypted) after you log in; it uses your log in password to decrypt your home. If you are not logged in, then your home directory is inaccessible entirely.

Comment: @David Agree, that's why of the question.

Comment: I realize I'm late, but the reason I'm running into is the 143 character limit in filenames. Copying my `Music` directory from a non-encrypted filesystem is leading to hundreds of errors.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can. The short and dirty description of how to do it is this:

1. Copy your files out of your home directory to another (unencrypted)
   location.
2. Move or remove the encrypted home directory out of the
   way.
3. Restore your files.

The actual process is more complicated than this. The [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#How_to_Remove_an_Encrypted_Private_Directory_Setup) assumes you've already moved your data without telling you how; this [description](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225023419/http://virtually-a-machine.blogspot.com/2010/08/howto-disable-ecryptfs.html) from Virtually Machine shows you how.

In short:

1. Log in as root.
2. Move the encrypted home directory so it mounts not on the home directory, but on a directory called `Private` in your home directory.
3. Move everything out of the `~/Private` directory into `~`.
4. Remove ecryptfs if desired.

See [Virtually Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225023419/http://virtually-a-machine.blogspot.com/2010/08/howto-disable-ecryptfs.html) for more specifics.

I would recommend logging out and back in just after the move: this makes sure everything is updated in your environment and so on.