# How to remove encryption password

Tags: password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption)

Recently i installed ubuntu 12.10 on my system and by mistake put up an encryption password, the password that is required to load ubuntu. Although i know that password, but i need to remove that. Please help me

Comment: Please see possible duplicate questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107410/can-you-unencrypt-remove-encryption-from-a-user-home-folder, http://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption