# How do i stop Ubuntu from asking for a password to decrypt my drive on start up?

Tags: password, encryption, luks

Ubuntu keeps asking for me to decrypt my drive on start up. This is expected, because I had set up full-disk encryption.

How do I stop this now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I disable encrypted file system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/can-i-disable-encrypted-file-system)

Comment: George's link explains how to remove encryption, but I wonder if the OP would be happy with a solution that required a USB device to unencrypt the disk instead of a password?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can't stop it.
When this encryption has been only applied on your home folder it is [possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107410/can-you-unencrypt-remove-encryption-from-a-user-home-folder).

Comment: Are you saying there is *no way* to convert an encrypted drive to an unencrypted drive?