# How do I increase the size of my root filesystem, not partition?

Tags: partitioning, 17.04

I am using a fresh Ubuntu server install and have a 30GB disk allocated to it. However, I only have 15GB of usable space:
[image]

My physical volume:
[image]

fdisk:[image]

Can I expand this? If so, how? If not, why? I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux so please forgive any ignorance on how this all works.

Comment: Please copy and paste the texts from the images

Comment: @George Sorry, this isn't over SSH, I can't copy/paste at the moment :/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was because of my `ecryptfs` filesystem.

I first had to remove it, following this post: [How can I completely remove ecryptfs from my system and delete .Private?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128583/how-can-i-completely-remove-ecryptfs-from-my-system-and-delete-private/333436)

I saw some comments about messed up logins afterwards so I recreated my home directory just in case before restarting.

I then resized the logical partition with `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/root` this resizes it to use the remainder of the free space.