# How to disable encrypted home directory?

Tags: encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption)

I know having an encrypted home directory is a great security function but I want to disable it. I am using Acronis True Image Server for Linux to backup my files and partition (in power on state, not offline).

After mounting Acronis image, my home directory contains no files. I cant find any of my files. The only files I see are directories named `/.encryptfs_fnek_encrypted_looonggstuffid????`  in `/home/.encryptfs/myusername/.Private`

So I want to disable home encryption, but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try:

```
ecryptfs-setup-private --undo
```

But other user suggest a longer method:

1st thing to do : BACKUP YOUR HOME
I can't say it louder... basically undoing encryption is equivalent to resetting (`rm -rf`) your `/home`, which is in fact hidden by a mount.

2nd step : log out of any desktop manager and go to a virtual console (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`)
Finally : for details :

```
 ecryptfs-setup-private --undo
```

In the event that you want to remove your `eCryptfs` Private Directory setup,
you will need to very carefully perform the following actions manually:

1. Obtain your Private directory mountpoint

   PRIVATE=`cat ~/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt 2>/dev/null || echo $HOME/Private`
2. Ensure that you have moved all relevant data out of your $PRIVATE directory
3. Unmount your encrypted private directory

> ecryptfs-umount-private

4. Make your Private directory writable again

> ```
> chmod 700 $PRIVATE
> ```

5. Remove $PRIVATE, ~/.Private, ~/.ecryptfs
   Note: THIS IS VERY PERMANENT, BE VERY CAREFUL

> rm -rf $PRIVATE ~/.Private ~/.ecryptfs

6. Uninstall the utilities (this is specific to your Linux distribution)

> sudo apt-get remove ecryptfs-utils libecryptfs0

I would say step 5 is a bit wrong : there's no need to delete $PRIVATE, which was for me my home....

After `.Private` and `.ecryptfs` deletion, just restore your `/home` :]

Comment: Thank you men, i will test it on a virtual machine first, so as i understand its very dangerous operation, and needs attention.

Comment: Couldn't login after this. Lucky I took a snapshot. In the end I created a temp admin account, deleted my old account, created it again, then deleted the temporary account.

Comment: Same here, this broke my login.

Comment: Unmounting did not work in my environment (Ubuntu 18.04): `sudo su -` - `root@myName_computer:~# ecryptfs-umount-private` - `fopen: No such file or directory` - `Cannot chdir into mountpoint.`.