# Is there a way to test if I will be able to login again?

Tags: login, encryption, encfs

I messed up with my files... Again... Now I am concerned if I will be able to login again once I logout. Is there a way to test if the essentials files are all there?

1. My home was encrypted during the installation (Ubuntu 12.04).
2. By login I mean boot Ubuntu into `lightdm`, type my password and be able to use my files which are encrypted and should be decrypted after the login.
3. By messed up I mean I have moved all my ".xml" files under user directory. I do not care that much for the configuration of the applications, neither for my keyboard shortcuts as I have a backup for them.
4. I can run `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` and it shows me the passphrase.
5. At `~/.ecryptfs` I have `auto-mount  auto-umount  Private.mnt  Private.sig  wrapped-passphrase`.

One Ecryptfs manual says:

```
$ man ecryptfs-setup-private


FILES
   ~/.ecryptfs/auto-mount

   ~/.Private - underlying directory containing encrypted data

   ~/Private - mountpoint containing decrypted data (when mounted)

   ~/.ecryptfs/Private.sig - file containing signature of mountpoint passphrase

   ~/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt - file containing path of the private directory mountpoint

   ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase - file containing the mount passphrase, wrapped with the login passphrase

   ~/.ecryptfs/wrapping-independent  -  this  file  exists  if  the wrapping passphrase is independent from login passphrase
```

May be those all are the required files?

Edit:
I rebooted the computer and although I have lost the configuration of applications and Keyboard Shortcuts I was able to login again. So I can say that no xml file is needed to login into an Ubuntu encrypted home.
But the question remains valid: is there a way to test if one will be able to login in the next boot?

Comment: What did you "mess up"? Are you asking about log in (pam, gdm, lightdm, kdm?) or encryption (ecryptfs)? Please clarify your problem and question. More likely then not the bottom line is going to be to log out an try it. If you can not log in you will have to boot to recovery mode and fix the problem, but hard to tell from what little you posted.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thank you Bodhi, I clarify the problem in my question now.

Comment: I am not sure how those configuration files would cause a problem with decrytping you home directory. You can not really "test" ecryptfs (encryption) without loging out because if you log in to a terminal, or ssh, while you remain previously logged in, the files will remain decrypted. You could probably manually re-encrypt yoru /home directory, but doing so while logged into X is going to be more hassle then it is worth.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Do you know which are the "essentials" files of ecrypts?

Comment: As far as I know, the only essential files / directories in your home directory are in .Private and .ectyptfs See - http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/06/migrating-to-encrypted-home-directory.html and http://askubuntu.com/questions/138950/how-to-disable-encrypted-home-directory but as you are not having a problem ...

Comment: With that edit those appear to be the required files.

Comment: One possible way to test is to copy your entire home folder into another system, or virtual system, but not a very convenient solution.

Comment: @Sparhawk A lot of disk space and time would be required. But are you sure it would reflect the actual state of the "original" system? Because as the "original" home is mounted the copied home wouldn't be identical.

Comment: @desgua To be honest, I'm not sure. However, I thought this might be equivalent to a situation where your computer crashes and you have your home folder preserved in its "mounted" state. I imagine that if it mounts after a pseudo-crash, then it should mount normally. I agree that a lot of disk space and time required, which is why I only posted this as a comment.

Comment: @Sparhawk Nevertheless this was the best solution so far.

Comment: @desgua I've added it as an answer just in case there are no better ones. I imagine it should work in theory, even if it's probably more painful than just trying to log out/in immediately.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to copy your entire home folder into another system (or virtual system), and see if you can log into this system.

This is not ideal and suffers from a few shortcomings.

- It's not very convenient, as you would need to install a parallel system, and copy across an entire home folder (although you could exclude personal documents).
- Since you don't want to risk logging out, the copied home directory will be copied from its "mounted" state, which might differ from the "logged out" state. However, I imagine that this is equivalent to a situation where your computer crashes and your home folder is preserved in its "mounted" state. I imagine that if it can mount after this pseudo-crash, then it should mount under normal circumstances.

Comment: I will give you the bounty because it is the best answer so far although I think that there must be a better way to check it. Congratulations!

Comment: @desgua. This won't work because you are forgetting that the installed files are in system folders and files so you need to replicate the entire system if that is to work. There are build system's for testing in the way you seek to describe. As far as I know ubuntu don't use one, gnome do and so do opensuse

Comment: @Magpie I guess you are right.

Comment: @desgua Thanks! (Although feel free to revoke it if there's a better answer.) I didn't say it was perfect. Anyway, to solves @Magpie's probably legitimate concerns, you could also replicate the entire system too. In my case, this makes it only slightly less feasible, since `/` is so small compared to `~`.

Answer (score 1):

The is no method that I know of to do what you describe. However if you struggle to graphically login to can get around this by login in via the terminal

**Step One**

boot and press `e` i the grub dialogue.

**Step Two**

Move the cursor down to the line which loads your kernel.

If you don't know what to look for then it should say something like either `linux` or `linuxefi` and be a long string of various letters, numbers and spaces that look like jibberish.

the line after it should say something like `initrd` -( you essentially need to go to the very end of the line just before the cursor reaches newline with `initrd`)

**Step Three**

type the followin before the end of the line (from step two)

> rw init=/bin/bash

**Step Four**

press `F10` to boot

**Step Five**

when you are in the terminal type

```
login yourusername
```

you will be prompted for your password and this should give you access.

**Step Six**

Type:

```
startx
```

to get to a graphical login

**Step Seven**

if that doesn't work the error in `/var/logs/Xorg.0` should tell you why it did not work and help you fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Magpie. The /var/logs/Xorg.0 file would be a guide in the search for a solution. But the question is if, in the future, I mess something up again, how can I test without risking loosing my files?

Comment: you won't lose your files if you are able to login via terminal

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to log in.  I mean because the fact that you logged in again. I'm pretty sure those are all the needed files. I have a older version of Ubuntu and I after messing with the files was able to log in.

Comment: Yes I am able to login. But if, in the future, I mess something up again, how can I test without risking loosing my files?

Comment: You may be able to copy the log in files and test them on a vurtal machine.