# Using an old home partition during installation

Tags: 14.04, reinstall

I want to reinstall ubuntu but I don't have to do it without losing any data in home partition(encrypted). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Keeping your /home partition untouched, reinstall ubuntu (This time no seperate /home partition and keep the same user name)
2. Use these guides to mount and remove remove encryption of your old encrypted /home partition

http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

[How to disable encrypted home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138950/how-to-disable-encrypted-home-directory)

3. using **chown** and **chmod**, set the permissions and ownership correctly.
4. Set it as your new /home partition

For that type

```
sudo blkid
```

Locate the UUID of your old /home partition.

Edit the fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following text to the fstab file on a new line, replacing the xxxxxxxx portion with the full UUID of your old home partition

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx    /home     ext4     nodev,nosuid     0     2
```

Rename your current home to home_old and create an empty /home folder

```
cd / && sudo mv /home /home_old && sudo mkdir /home
```

5. Restart