# failed encryption

Tags: 12.04, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative (root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password)

I just installed xubuntu 12.04, and things seemed to be going fine. I clicked on the updates message and started the updates. A message popped up asking me to encrypt my passphrase, so I told it to proceed. I started typing in my passphrase and noticed that nothing was appearing in the entry box. I tried clicking on it and typing again, but nothing appeared. I figure, well I'll do this later and closed the box. After my updates completed I re-started xubuntu and now it tells me that my password is incorrect. I tried different fragments of the password in case some of the typing went through but didn't appear in the encryption box, but this too was futile.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You mention both an encryption passphrase and a password. Since you were installing I assume you are talking about your login password and, therefore, this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password . As you can see that happens to people pretty frequently. If you are talking about something else please edit your question to be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: If you had set up file system encryption this may be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption . Again, if it's something else please speak up by editing this question.