# Cannot change login background / Also not auto changing

Tags: login, desktop-background

I have two machines running Ubuntu 13.10. One of the machines is changing the login wallpaper while choosing an account.

I would like to have this on the other machine as well. But nothing changes while changing background. I tried Ubuntu Tweak to choose a default login background, but all the options are greyed out.

I have searched the internet. I placed the background already in the default folder: usr/share/background. Changed the owner to root like the other wallpapers and also the permissions. Nothing changes.

Anyone an idea what I can do to let this work?

-->

Found out that there was a little lock in Ubuntu Tweak. My Ubuntu Tweak is not greyed out anymore. I changed the login background... but it does not change after logging out to what I want... is just became black.

Comment: The background changes to that of the user's that is selected *(try selecting the Guest Session or something to see the difference)*, but this won't work if the home directory is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks @wilf... you gave me the solution!!! My home folder is encrypted indeed. I've changed the image to the one in the default background folder, and now it is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work if your home folder on the machine is encrypted. This will be because it will need access to that image for it to work, and it can't if it is encrypted. There are varying ways of doing this:

You can [decrypt you home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption) <sub>*Be VERY Careful..*</sub>

Or just use an image outside the home directory, like the default ones in `/usr/share/backgrounds`, or just copy the file to `/home` or somewhere that is not encrypted, and then set it.

You can also [Change the Wallpaper in LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm/64002#64002)

Hope this helps ;-)