# Delay mounts after encrypted home folder is ready

Tags: mount, encryption, home-directory, fstab, ecryptfs

I have set up a few bind mounts in `fstab`, mounting one folder in my home directory to another (AeroFS no sym-link circumvent). My home folder is encrypted.

When the system boots up, it attempts to mount the folders inside home folder prior to mounting the encrypted home folder itself, causing an error.

How can I edit `fstab` to have the encrypted home folder mount first?

I tried adding `noauto`, it didn't work.

EDIT: Also, I want to maintain the encryption for security reasons.

`fstab` content:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=8e26dd0d-f57f-4b63-93b3-7f2743d6fe7a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C2BB-18A8  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=062418c7-ba50-40e4-b3ea-42663e92eba8 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=ac66f7ee-7dbe-4e56-9f42-459038a11a12 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

#
#Bind mounts for AeroFS to sync outside it's folder:
#
/home/user/Desktop  /home/user/AeroFS/Desktop   none    bind    0   0
/home/user/Documents    /home/user/AeroFS/Documents none    bind    0   0
/home/user/Music    /home/user/AeroFS/Music     none    bind    0   0
/home/user/Pictures /home/user/AeroFS/Pictures  none    bind    0   0
#
```

lsblk output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   954M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0  55.9G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0  14.9G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0   394G  0 part /home
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption)

Comment: No, I am certainly not interested to stop using home directory encryption.

Comment: What is the point of using ecrypts if your data is automatically decrypted at boot ?

Comment: I have many reasons for choosing to use it, one of them is that it's a portable laptop. In any case, decrypting the home folder is out of the question.

Comment: If you automatically decrypt your data when you boot it defeats any advantage of encryption as your data is only encrypted when the laptop is off and is available to anyone who boots the system. With what you posted I highly suggest you reinstall using LUKS and encrypt your entire install with LUKS. Skip encrypting home. Your data will then be encrypted the way you wish and your mount binds will work.

Comment: Could you please post your fstab to http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the output of `gparted --list` so we can have a look???  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby: I posted fstab and my disk configuration. Please take a look.

Comment: @Panther your remarks are _completely_ besides the point (yes, I also looked at the original revision of this question). I am looking for a similar thing. I do not want my home folder to go unencrypted, but I certainly don't care for the read-only bind-mount to my music collection to be encrypted. And so in order to mix and match things the only way of making the desired location available from my home folder _while_ using encryption for the home folder is to delay the mount operation. So perfectly valid use cases.

Comment: @Dean you probably have moved on from this, but making this a `user` mount and using the options `noauto,x-systemd.automount` did the job for me. This way a script inserted to auto-start upon login can perform the `mount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:

1. Remove the following lines from fstab:

   ```
   #
   #Bind mounts for AeroFS to sync outside it's folder:
   #
   /home/user/Desktop  /home/user/AeroFS/Desktop   none    bind    0   0
   /home/user/Documents    /home/user/AeroFS/Documents none    bind    0   0
   /home/user/Music    /home/user/AeroFS/Music     none    bind    0   0
   /home/user/Pictures /home/user/AeroFS/Pictures  none    bind    0   0
   #
   ```
2. create the following shell script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   # This script binds AeroFS mounts to sync outside their folder,
   # as an answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/604361/delay-mounts-after-encrypted-home-folder-is-ready
   # 
   # Copyright (c) 2014 Fabby

   # This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   # This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
   # You DID NOT receive a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program as the license is bigger then this program.

   mount --bind /home/user/Desktop   /home/user/AeroFS/Desktop
   mount --bind /home/user/Documents /home/user/AeroFS/Documents
   mount --bind /home/user/Music     /home/user/AeroFS/Music
   mount --bind /home/user/Pictures  /home/user/AeroFS/Pictures
   ```
3. Save it under `/home/user/bin/MountAeroFS.sh` (create the `bin` directory if it doesn't exist.)
4. Open Startup Applications, and add the following *Command:* `MountAeroFS.sh`.
   As *Name:* and *Comment:* you can add anything to remind you what this is about.
5. Reboot (as you've just changed your `fstab`)

### Done!

Comment: I will try it. But, just out of curiosity, shouldn't fstab be able to handle this in a "built-in" manner? It seems strange that this wasn't taken into account.

Comment: Lol did you add license to script with 4 mounts

Comment: @Peter No I **did not  :D**. An upvote would be nice if I made you laugh! **;-)**

Comment: how is this supposed to work when `only root can use "--bind" option`?

Comment: @derrend exactly ... this is a very naïve "solution". It _may_ work if `/etc/fstab` _does_ list the mount points with option `noauto,user` (not sure this works with `bind`) and then it's unnecessary to explicitly give the `--bind` or `-o bind` when invoking `mount`. But not sure if this _could_ work. Also PAM modules may be able to do this ...

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work since non-root users are not able to use the `--bind` option.

What I used instead was `bindfs`. It allows non-root users to create bound mounts.

First install `bindfs`: `sudo apt install bindfs`. Then, open `/etc/fuse.conf` and uncomment the line `user_allow_other`.

Then, in your startup script (which runs after you log in), use the following commands to mount:

```
bindfs /home/user/Desktop   /home/user/AeroFS/Desktop
bindfs /home/user/Documents /home/user/AeroFS/Documents
bindfs /home/user/Music     /home/user/AeroFS/Music
bindfs /home/user/Pictures  /home/user/AeroFS/Pictures
```