# ecryptfs _readpage?

Tags: ecryptfs, logs

I was taking a look at the logs, for safety, and I have found those logs below:

```
nori-hidamari kernel: [ 1829.683564] ecryptfs_decrypt_page: Error
attempting to read lower page; rc = [-4] 
Apr  9 08:52:13 nori-hidamari
kernel: [ 1829.683569] ecryptfs_readpage: Error decrypting page; rc =
[-4]
```

ecryptfs probably has something with encryption, but what that log actually means?

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

`ecryptfs` allows you to encrypt specific folders, like your home directory. Unforuntately, the [official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory) on encrypted folders seems to be very out of date.

I get these same errors and haven't found any good information about how to fix them. The configuration lives in `~/.ecryptfs`, but that's about all I've been able to understand.

Unless you have particularly sensitive data, keeping it encrypted may not be necessary. It seems to create a risk of not being able to recover your data if something goes wrong. [Another AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption) with several answers explains how to safely remove `encrypts`, which would presumably stop the errors. I haven't tried it myself.