# Ubuntu 16.04 - Trying to disable home folder encryption

Tags: 16.04, password, encryption

I am trying to disable the home folder encryption on my Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed this tutorial, but unfortunately something went wrong:

http://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/

First all was working well, but after restarting I noticed that the cryptsetup prompt after bootup is still there (and so is the encryption?).

How can I fix this without reinstalling the hole system?
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I mean Ubuntu 16.04. Please remove the off-topic marking.

Comment: Same problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption

Answer (score 2):

There two kinds of encryption in *buntu Linux:

1. full disk encryption (with LUKS)
2. home folder encryption

Is it possible you have enabled both of them but disabled only the second one?

Luks (1) asks you specifically for disk encryption password at the very beginning of the system booting. Home folder encryption (2) is kinda invisible, i.e. you get asked not for the encryption password but simply for the login and password to the system, those also do the decryption for you. When you follow steps from the guide you linked you just disable the home folder encryption, you are still going to be asked for the login and password to the system (this you can now disable in GUI in Settings > Users and Groups) AND if you also enabled the full disk encryption (1) when installing the system, for the password to decrypt the whole disk. I am not sure if it is possible to also disable full disk encryption (1).