# What Packages Does KDE Vaults Need to Operate?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, encryption, ecryptfs

I'm planning on un-encrypting my home directory for easily moving it to an SSD (by following this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/a/4960/645874), but I'm not sure if this will affect KDE Vaults.

Does KDE Vaults rely on the packages `ecryptfs-utils` or `libecryptfs0`? If so, is their un-installation necessry?

Comment: If you've already got vaults installed, just use synaptic or a `--simulate` option in a terminal and see what else removing the two ecryptfs pacakges would want to do - just don't actually do it. Synaptic shows changes before actually applying them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ubuntu `plasma-vault` package page for 18.04/bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/plasma-vault) doesn't mention "ecryptfs" in any of the dependencies, so I'd say no.

But, there's nothing like getting a custom answer about your specific system, so you can always simulate a remove (or install) to see what other packages would be removed (or added) with a package manager interface like Synaptic, or just

```
apt-get --simulate remove plasma-vault
```

The relevant lines should be similar to this non-vaults example:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libecryptfs1 libtspi1
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ecryptfs-utils
```

Comment: Yep, I uninstalled the packages that the tutorial called for, they didn't conflict with `plasma-vault`.