# Ubuntu Server - Synchronize Dropbox with no logged user

Tags: 16.04, server, services, sync, dropbox

Intalled dropbox from https://www.dropbox.com/en/install-linux and downloaded the Python script.
Then configured my account and it works ok.

My goal is to have dropbox uploading new files created on the user directory, regardless that user is logged in or not.

I tried with the script below but it fails with a 203 error and restart over and 203 again. Once I log in with that user the daemon works with no problems.
Any idea?, how can I trace that 203/EXEC error?

content of ***/etc/systemd/system/dropbox.service***

```
[Unit]
Description=Dropbox Daemon.
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=server
ExecStart=/home/server/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**journalctl -u dropbox.service**

```
systemd[1]: Started Dropbox Daemon.
systemd[1]: dropbox.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
systemd[1]: dropbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: dropbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: dropbox.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Dropbox Daemon.
```

and once I log in:

```
dropboxd[1616]: dropbox: locating interpreter
dropboxd[1616]: dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-Y5jTff
dropboxd[1616]: dropbox: initializing
dropboxd[1616]: dropbox: initializing python 3.7.2
dropboxd[1616]: dropbox: setting program path '/home/server/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86-84.4.170/dropbox'
dropboxd[1616]: dropbox: python initialized
dropboxd[1616]: dropbox: running dropbox
```

**sudo journalctl -xe**

```
systemd[1448]: dropbox.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/server/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /home/server/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd could not be executed
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the home directory was encrypted!
Just followed [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption) to disable encryption, reboot and it works.